# How can I run a second cURL process based on the results of the first process?

Tags: php, postgresql, curl

I am using curl to run a SQL query in order to create a table in a database. Here is the working code:

```
 // defines the post vars
 $apikey = $_POST['apikey'];
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $tablename = $_POST['tablename'];

 //SQL create table statment
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . (string)$tablename . " (post_id integer, post_title text, post_content text, post_date date, post_type text, permalink_guid text);";
 $sql2 = "SELECT cdb_cartodbfytable('" . (string)$tablename . "');";

 // initializing curl
 $ch = curl_init( "https://".$username.".cartodb.com/api/v2/sql" );
 $query = http_build_query(array('q'=>$sql,'api_key'=>$apikey));
 $query2 = http_build_query(array('q'=>$sql2,'api_key'=>$apikey));

 // configuring curl options
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

 //result
 $result_jsonstring = curl_exec($ch);
 $result = json_decode($result_jsonstring);
 echo(print_r($result));
```

With this code I can get one two success responses. If the table creation was successful:

```
stdClass Object
(
[rows] => Array
    (
    )

[time] => 0.013
[fields] => stdClass Object
    (
    )

[total_rows] => 0
)
1
```

If the table name already exists in the database, I get this:

```
stdClass Object
(
[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => relation "tablename" already exists
    )

)
1
```

I also can successfully run a second query replacing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);` with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query2);`

The problem that I am having is getting the second query to run if the first query was successful (table created, but not run if the table exists). Here is the code that I have attempted to accomplish this:

```
// defines the post vars
$apikey = $_POST['apikey'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$tablename = $_POST['tablename'];

//SQL create table statment
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . (string)$tablename . " (post_id integer, post_title text, post_content text, post_date date, post_type text, permalink_guid text);";

// initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( "https://".$username.".cartodb.com/api/v2/sql" );
$query = http_build_query(array('q'=>$sql,'api_key'=>$apikey));

// configuring curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//result
$result_jsonstring = curl_exec($ch);

//close the curl session
curl_close($ch);

if (TRUE === $result_jsonstring)
        echo "It was true!";
        echo(print_r($result_jsonstring));

        ch2 = curl_init( "https://".$username.".cartodb.com/api/v2/sql" );
        $sql2 = "SELECT cdb_cartodbfytable('" . (string)$tablename . "');";
        $query2 = http_build_query(array('q'=>$sql2,'api_key'=>$apikey));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query2);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result_jsonstring2 = curl_exec($ch2);

        echo(print_r($result_jsonstring2));

        curl_close($ch2);
```

Here are the problems that I having with this:
1)The second curl request is not working. I get a message that says I must "supply a sql query" and I am not sure why. I do get the "It was true!" statement however.
2) I keep getting the number 1 at the end of the response. In the final case, I am getting two (11).

```
{"rows":[],"time":0.008,"fields":{},"total_rows":0}It was true!11{"error":["You must indicate a sql query"]}11
```

How can I successfully run the second curl process only if a table was successfully created?

Comment: Sorry the question is so long, just trying to be concise. :)

Comment: You would help yourself immensely if you wrapped your cURL in a function /class->method and made it reusable. It could return false or an array, then you could base your next action on that response. You could use the same cURL function to call again on success of first. It will help you maintain consistent data integrity. You will know that the function will return one or the other. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Going to have to Google that though (pretty new to this).

Comment: Yeah! Try creating a function first, that is easier to do than set up a class with methods an such. When you get it worked out, then try a class system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the two last curl_setop's to use $ch2 rather than $ch.

Comment: Ha thanks! I can't believe after all that, that is all it was. Any idea on how to eliminate the 1's i get at the end of the response?

Comment: My guess is that the 1's comes from you using echo on the boolean value true that print_r returns after it prints the response. So test without the echo functions...

Comment: You were right, that was the source of the 1's. Though I thought the echo's were producing json code output in the response, which is apparently derived from something else. How can I prevent that from appearing?